# Can't connect Boost Locale library using G++

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I am trying to compile a C++ project with the Boost Locale and Filesystem libraries. Here is the command:

`g++ czech2017.cpp dist/jsoncpp.cpp dist/sqlite3.o -o czech2017 -LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_locale -lboost_thread`

but I get the following errors.

```
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text+0x965): undefined reference to `boost::locale::generator::generator()'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text+0x9b4): undefined reference to `boost::locale::generator::generate(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text+0xa15): undefined reference to `boost::locale::generator::~generator()'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text+0xa3a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale const&)'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text+0xb87): undefined reference to `boost::locale::generator::~generator()'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEE[_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEE]+0x15): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEE[_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKcS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEEE]+0x32): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKwS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKwS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x15): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN0DX4g.o:czech2017.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKwS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN5boost10filesystem11path_traits7convertEPKwS3_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x32): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
```

I know I am not linking something properly. I assume I dont have the libararies linked in the correct order, but I don't know the proper order. Can anyone help?

**Edit:**

Ok so this is now really weird. I created the following CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(election_results_calculators)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system locale thread)

set (ROOT_DIR ..)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(czech2017 ${ROOT_DIR}/tests/czech2017.cpp ${ROOT_DIR}/tests/dist/sqlite3.o ${ROOT_DIR}/tests/dist/jsoncpp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(czech2017 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

And it compiles. I get the same error as above, but now with slightly different words: `__imp__ZN5boost6locale9generatorC1Ev`. If I compile the program with a rough approximation of the CMake compile command: `g++.exe -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_CHRONO_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_LOCALE_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK  -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++17 -o czech2017.exe -c czech2017.cpp` it also compiles correctly, but I get a message saying the exe is incompatible with 64bit windows. Why would it compile if it wasn't?

Comment: Please reference [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help investigate the problem

Comment: Linker error related to boost_locale and boost_filesystem not being found. Where are the binaries for those installed? If they're not under "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib", you will have to specify additional `-L` paths with their directories.

Comment: @dratenik That doesn't seem to be the problem. The "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib" file has boost_filesystem.dll, boost_filesystem.lib, boost_locale.dll, and boost_locale.lib

Comment: Are they for the right architecture? You are compiling for 64 bits (I'm guessing), maybe those are 32-bit libraries? Not sure how to tell, possibly with the [file utility](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-file?repo=mingw64)

Comment: @dratenik it seems that they are 64bits, which is what I am running.